# App for remembering different mouses' tracking speeds?

Tags: applications, mouse

I'm just wondering if there is an app/prefpane to remember different tracking speeds for different mouses when you have a Macbook and are switching between mouses constantly?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/customization/customize-the-functionality-of-your-macs-mouse/), [Steermouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) will allow you to save different profiles on the mouses (among other things).

> ### Build Profiles
>
> One of the best features of Steermouse is the ability
> to have multiple profiles. This works well if you have multiple people
> using a mouse that all prefer different settings, if you have more
> than once mouse that you use on a regular basis, or if you would
> prefer to use different mouse settings for different tasks, workflows,
> games, etc.